# How to improve this sql query

Tags: sql

Here I get the "ProcessTime" in hours and minutes, but in case of seconds only I check for the opposite condition (see code below)

Is there any way to improve that?

```
select convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,101) as [Date], tmb.WO, tc.WOCategory, count(IdSingle) QtyProd, tb.Brand, tm.Model, 
        (case when (DateDiff(mi, Min(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)), Max(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)))/60%24 > 0) then 
            convert(varchar(5), DateDiff(mi, Min(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)), Max(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)))/60%24) + 'h '              
                else
            ''
        end) +
        (case when (DateDiff(mi, Min(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)), Max(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)))%60 > 0) then
            convert(varchar(5), DateDiff(mi, Min(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)), Max(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)))%60) + 'm'              
                else
            ''
        end) +          
        (case when 
            (DateDiff(mi, Min(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)), Max(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)))/60%24 <= 0) and 
            (DateDiff(mi, Min(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)), Max(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)))%60 <= 0) then 
            '< 1 min' 
            else 
            ''
        end) ProcessTime
```

Comment: What version of sql are you using?

Comment: sorry for the late, sql server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL Server 2005 you can use a CTE to improve this query.
Something like this:

```
;WITH minmax AS
(
   SELECT someKey, 
          DateDiff(mi, Min(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8)), Max(convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,8))) as mdiff
   FROM tablename
   GROUP BY fieldName
)
Select convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,101) as [Date], tmb.WO, tc.WOCategory, count(IdSingle) QtyProd, tb.Brand, tm.Model, 
        (case when (mdiff/60%24 > 0) then 
            convert(varchar(5), mdiff/60%24) + 'h '              
                else
            ''
        end) +
        (case when (mdiff%60 > 0) then
            convert(varchar(5), mdiff%60) + 'm'              
                else
            ''
        end) +          
        (case when 
            (DateDiff(mi, mdiff/60%24 <= 0) and (DateDiff(mi, mdiff%60 <= 0) then 
            '< 1 min' 
            else 
            ''
        end) ProcessTime
from tablename
join minmax on tablename.somekey = minmax.somekey
```